# Вопрос по структуре предложения

Tags: спп, сложное-предложение

*Вечером, когда все уснули, ветер, рыдающий за окном, бушевал так сильно, что ломались ветви деревьев и трещали и скрипели заборы.*

Вот моя попытка понять, как устроено это предложение:

***[, (когда — ═), — , |п.о.|, ═], (что ═ —) и (═ и ═ —).***

Есть сомнения насчет двух последних частей.

Comment: Egor, хорошая попытка. А какие именно сомнения?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Для меня странно, что последняя часть не содержит подчинительного союза, с таким еще не сталкивался. Вот и думаю, может что-то тут похитрее, может связь другая... А вы как думаете?

Comment: Две последние части – это однородные придаточные предложения, соединённые союзом ***и***, запятая в таких случаях не ставится. Повтор подчинительного союза необязателен, а часто и нежелателен. А в этом случае вообще его не втиснуть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Схема предложения** (без обозначения предикативных основ и обособленного оборота):

**[, (когда),  так + нареч.],  (что) и ( что).**

**Примечание**. Союз ЧТО не повторяется, но относится к обоим придаточным предложениям (это общее следствие), так что его можно не писать.

1. В предложении **4 предикативные**  основы,  подчинительная и сочинительная связь.
2. Подчинительная связь **параллельная**, к главному придаточному относятся: (1) придаточное **времени** (союз ***КОГДА***) и (2) два однородных придаточных (союз ***ЧТО***), связанных союзом ***И.***
3. Вторая связь **местоименно-союзная** со значением степени признака и следствия: ***ТАК* сильно, *ЧТО***.  Местоименная часть «так сильно»  входит в главное предложение.

**ВЫВОД**

Таким образом, ваша схема верна, но местоименно-союзную связь надо **обозначить на схеме:** [так + нареч.], что...

Определение **вида придаточного** входит в обязательную программу: это придаточное "степень признака + следствие", а не просто следствие.